# Android - download JSON file from url

Tags: java, android, json, file, url

Is it possible to download a file with JSON data inside it from a URL? Also, the files I need to get have no file extension, is this a problem or can i force it to have a .txt extension upon download?

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention, that the website requires a username and password entered in order to access the site which i know. There a way to input these values in as I retrieve the file?

Comment: Hi, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576513/android-download-binary-file-problems).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using URLConnection?

```
private InputStream getStream(String url) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        return urlConnection.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also remember to encode your params like this:

```
String action="blabla";
InputStream myStream=getStream("http://www.myweb.com/action.php?action="+URLEncoder.encode(action));
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the inputstream :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Like others have pointed out, basic URL is a good enough starting point.

While other code examples work, the actual accessing of JSON content can be one-liner. With [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) JSON library, you could do:

```
Response resp = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new URL("http://dot.com/api/?customerId=1234").openStream(),Response.class);
```

if you wanted to bind JSON data into 'Response' that you have defined: to get a Map, you would instead do:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new URL("http://dot.com/api/?customerId=1234").openStream(), Map.class);
```

as to adding user information; these are typically passed using [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), in which you pass base64 encoded user information as "Authorization" header.
For that you need to open HttpURLConnection from URL, and add header; JSON access part is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/JanithaR/ff97f074c18b3eea0e0b) is a class file and an interface I have written to download JSON data from a URL. As for the username password authentication, that will depend on how it's implemented on the website you're accessing.