# Android: read JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to read from a url the following data:

```
{"to": "DKK", "rate": 7.4417, "from": "EUR"}
```

And I'm trying to read it with this code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject(site);
String to = (String)obj2.get("to");
Double rate = obj2.getDouble("rate");
```

And I get the following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for http://rate-exchange-1.appspot.com/currency?from=EUR&to=DKK
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at com.converter.android.converter.ConvertActivity$Parse.doInBackground(ConvertActivity.java:1579)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at com.converter.android.converter.ConvertActivity$Parse.doInBackground(ConvertActivity.java:1547)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: First download JSON response and then parse. You can't directly get JSON by providing its URL to JSONObject.

Comment: How can I download JSON responde? @Sharj

Comment: @Elenasys I only have what I paste here

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem, you can´t directly get a Json Object using the url, because isn´t a json object:

```
JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject(site);
```

You will check some examples here:

[Android - download JSON file from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027395/android-download-json-file-from-url)

Download the file and then you will use the `getJSONObject()` method.

Comment: and the solution is?

Comment: See some examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027395/android-download-json-file-from-url to download your .json  :)