# Download Big media files in android

Tags: android

im trying to download media files through my application for which i wrote a method which read bytes from the source file and return bytes array,

byte[] mediainfo = getMediaFile(String path);

but the problem is that when the file size will become greater than 5 or 6MB it will return outofMemory exception,please kindly give some idea how i will download big media file about 10 mb through my application,
thanks.

Comment: Try to release objects in order to avoid out of memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a byte array for downloaded files is only ok if these files are small enough. For large files, I definitely recommend using the stream classes of Java. Here is an example: [Android download binary file problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576513/android-download-binary-file-problems)

Mind that you have to replace `f.write(buffer);` by `f.write(buffer,0, len1);` (as answered there) - otherwise you will get wrong data.