# android mp3 file download

Tags: android, file, download, webview, mp3

hello friends
I need to download mp3 file from the internet and to store it into the assets folder and also it must be played into the media player. How can i do it?

Comment: Please format your question. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: And accept some answers please.

Comment: [this][1] may help you in downloading mp3 files


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13163512/1447595

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Downloading a file, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576513/android-download-binary-file-problems).
2. Storeing to asset folder: not possible, you cannot modify your resources or assets after compile time. Store the file to the sdcard, see [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/save-file-to-sd-card.html).
3. Use [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to launch the file.