# How to download a pdf file in Android?

Tags: android, download

I want to download a pdf file from an url.
For viewing the pdf file I used the code below.

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");

if (file.exists()) {
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, "No Application Available to View PDF",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It is working but how do I get the pdf file from an url (e.g `http://.../example.pdf`). I want to **download** the pdf file from this url. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downloading a PDF works the same as downloading any other binary file.

1. Open a [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
2. Use the connection's [`getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) method to read the file.
3. Create a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and write the inputstream.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576513/android-download-binary-file-problems) for example source code.

Comment: But in Blundell answer the file will not be downloaded if pdf is not available in mobile.But i want to download pdf file from url and then the pdf will be show in webview. So this is the right answer for me.

Comment: Any plugin that does that? Sound like something generic

Answer (score 28):

Download a pdf:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf")));
```

Ah as I've just found out this is device dependent.

**scenarios**

1. It will download the pdf to your browser/downloaded/ folder
2. You have a google docs account - It will ask you to sign in then view the pdf in the browser
3. You have a pdf reader installed - App dependent may catch it may not

In all scenarios though the user has access to the PDF with one line of code :-)

Comment: @Blundell I tried the same with an MP4 url, but it opens the video in Google Chrome instead of starting the download. Any help?

Comment: how is this device dependant?what do you mean?

Comment: meaning either scenario 1, 2 or 3 could happen

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put lengthy code to open and download pdf in android you can just use below code to open and download pdf

```
String URL ="http://worldhappiness.report/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/03/HR-V1_web.pdf"

 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(URL)));
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369390/3908170) one... do you have anything to add to make yours different?

Comment: Separating this into two lines can save some junior developers the trouble of understanding the first answer.