# how to retrieve a pdf through android app

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am creating a mobile app in android studio which contains a lot of PDF file views for the users using app. I decided to store those PDF files in a server. But i don't know to how retrieve the files on my the app.Is there any way to retrieve the PDF on our app from the local server..
Hoping for reply..

Comment: you want to download pdf files from server and then view them using pdf reader installed on user device

Comment: yes sir.is there any way to do that

Comment: Possbile duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368788/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Just store the pdf files on your server using Multipart [Post multipart request with Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk) and then retrieve those files and store them in phone. Then you can use a filemanager https://github.com/nexes/Android-File-Manager to select and open the file.

For opening pdf you have to fire the intent which will open pdf file by using a preinstalled app or if you want to open by your app then there are several libraries like muPDF library, iText library(Java Library).

Comment: Sorry sir i did not understand what u meant? Actually that is my problem. Am sorry for that. I don't know anything much about Android Programming.So will u please explain the coding for that

Comment: Then you firstly must learn the basics as without knowing the basics it is pretty much tough to understand things.