# Downloading a single file with AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner in Android development. I'm trying to learn multi-threading and working with the internet so I'm doing that by downloading a PDF file from a link through the background thread using  `AsyncTask`. I have confusions about what the best way is to go about it.

Do I create the `URI` and other necessary connectivity objects in the `onCreate` or in the `doInBackground` method of the `AsyncTask` class?

To download just a single PDF file, what sort of objects do I need to call?

I have checked the documentation but I couldn't really understand it. I'd appreciate a layman's explanation and possibly pseudo-code.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button downloadPDF;
    DownloadingClass downPDF;
    private static final String TAG = "omar.asynctaskdemo;";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String urlExample = "https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Actionscript%20-%20Flash%20-%20Flex%20-%20Air/Flash%20Development%20for%20Android%20Cookbook%20-%20Labrecque%20-%20Packt%20%282011%29/Flash%20Development%20for%20Android%20Cookbook%20-%20Labrecque%20-%20Packt%20%282011%29.pdf");

        downloadPDF = findViewById(R.id.download_pdf);
        downPDF = new DownloadingClass();

        downloadPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downPDF.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadingClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: @AliKhaki That's a general Asynctask question.  I'm asking about best practices.  Where does the code for connectivity go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask just runs your code in the background thread. To download a pdf file is like any other file.

You will require to use `HttpUrlConnection`, Create a `FileOutputStream` and write the `inputstream`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576513/android-download-binary-file-problems)

Have the above code executed in `doInBackground` of AsyncTask class and better pass the url in the constructor and do everything inside the `doInBackground` method. Since you don't want to block the UI thread.

Comment: Which constructor?

Comment: new DownloadingClass("pass your url here")